# echo multiple variables with a space between each into echo'd table cell

Tags: php, echo

```
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['guest2First']))
echo '<tr><td>';
echo '<input type="text" name="guest2Ticket" id="guest2Ticket" onblur="isTicketNumber(this)"  size ="22"/>';
echo '</td><td>';
echo $first["guest2First"] , ' ', $middle["guest2Middle"] , ' ',$last["guest2Last"];
echo '</td></tr>'?>
```

I have a form that uses $_SESSION variables to fill in some of the content using the code above.

What I need to do is

1. check if a variable is set
2. if it is echo out a new table row containing two cells
3. in the first cell echo out an input box
4. **in the second cell echo out 3 variables with a space between each**

Everything seems to work fine except number 4. Nothing is is echo'd into the second cell.

Im sure that

```
echo $first["guest2First"] , ' ', $middle["guest2Middle"] , ' ',$last["guest2Last"];
```

is the problem. **How can I fix this syntax to achieve my desired result?**

Comment: Are you sure, `$first["guest2First"]`, `$last["guest2Last"]`, `$middle["guest2Middle"]` aren't empty?

Comment: Do a var_dump on $first, $last and $middle to confirm they contain the values you expect. Also, should there be an opening curly bracket after the if statement?

Comment: Man I feel stupid, somewhere along the line i changed $_SESSION to $first, $middle, and $last. I assumed that because the table row was showing up at all "guest2First" must be set and therefore my problem was likely the syntax mentioned above. @Philipp if you wanna post to check that the variables arent empty Ill accept it as the answer as that was what made me see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mixed the var names and mean $_SESSION, instead of $first, $middle, $last

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['guest2First']))
echo '<tr><td>';
echo '<input type="text" name="guest2Ticket" id="guest2Ticket" onblur="isTicketNumber(this)"  size ="22"/>';
echo '</td><td>';
echo $_SESSION["guest2First"] , ' ', $_SESSION["guest2Middle"] , ' ',$_SESSION["guest2Last"];
echo '</td></tr>'?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a couple of better syntax options:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['guest2First'])){

$name = $_SESSION["guest2First"].
        (isset($_SESSION["guest2Middle"])?' '.$_SESSION["guest2Middle"]:null).
        (isset($_SESSION["guest2Last"])?' '.$_SESSION["guest2Last"]:null);
?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="guest2Ticket" id="guest2Ticket" onblur="isTicketNumber(this);" size ="22"/></td>
    <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

Or

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['guest2First'])){
    echo '<tr>',
         '<td><input type="text" name="guest2Ticket" id="guest2Ticket" onblur="isTicketNumber(this);" size ="22"/></td>',
         '<td>'.$name.'</td>',
         '</tr>';
}
?>
```